# Android ConstraintLayout programmatically connect but only work top to top

Tags: java, android, constraints

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams navigationBarParams = 
    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, (int)(BAR_DEFAULT_HEIGHT_DP * density) );

    _navigationBar.setId(R.id.navigation_fragment_navigation_bar);
    _navigationBar.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    _navigationBar.setLayoutParams(navigationBarParams);
    _navigationBar.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    _navigationBar.setBaselineAligned(false);
    _navigationBar.setWeightSum(6f);
    _navigationBar.setElevation(20.0f);

    ConstraintLayout con = (ConstraintLayout)_rootView.findViewById(_rootConstraintLayoutId);
    con.addView(_navigationBar);
    
    ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
    set.clone(con);
    set.constrainWidth(_navigationBar.getId(), 0);
    set.connect(_navigationBar.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, con.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, 100 ); //work!
    set.connect(_navigationBar.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, con.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT,100 ); //not work!!
    set.connect(_navigationBar.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, con.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 100 ); //not work!!
    set.applyTo(con);
```

I add LinearLayout to root ConstraintLayout.
and connect constraint TOP to TOP, LEFT to LEFT, RIGHT to RIGHT with all value 100.
but only top value 100 is work.
not work left, right. what wrong my code?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Start and End instead. That way, your view will support different languages.

```
set.connect(boton.getId() , ConstraintSet.START , ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID , ConstraintSet.START , 80);
```

I know there is a bug reported on Google for that.

Answer (score -1):

android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

on that try removing it and use

"LinearLayout"

you will be able to change your orientation as you like.
by writing

andriod:oreiantation="horizontal" or andriod:oreiantation="vertiacl"

its your choice

Comment: I don't have issue with Orientation.